# Handling a list of buttons in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am working on a `SwiftUI` app (Xcode Version 12.4 and iOS 14.4.2) and am having problems to properly handle buttons in a list. I hope someone can point out the way to go.

Here is the relevant code:

```
struct CustomListView: View {
    var localList:[SomeManagedObject], moc:NSManagedObjectContext
    @State var showingOtherView = false
    @State var selectNbr:Int!
    
    func handleCustomItem(_ argument: SomeManagedObject) {
        print(#function+" (1):\(showingOtherView):")
        selectNbr = localList.firstIndex(of: argument)
        self.showingOtherView.toggle()
        print(#function+" (2):\(showingOtherView):\(selectNbr):")
        ..... Do useful things .....
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.localList) {
                item in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.handleCustomItem(item)
                    })
                    {
                        Text(item.expression!)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red))
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 11).padding(.vertical, 15)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingOtherView) {
            OtherView(parameter: localList[selectNbr])
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app this is what I get as ouput, which is what I expect:

```
handleCustomItem(_:) (1):false:
handleCustomItem(_:) (2):true:Optional(4):
```

Then I have a break point before running this line of code (to avoid a crash):

```
OtherView(parameter: localList[selectNbr])
```

This is where things get weird (unexpected for me), in the debugger I can see:

```
(lldb) p showingOtherView
(Bool) $R0 = false
(lldb) p selectNbr
(Int?) $R2 = nil
(lldb)
```

But I would expect *showingOtherView* to be *true*, and (more important) *selectNbr* to hold the value *4*. What is going on here that I am missing ?

Comment: In this case you should use [sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:))

Comment: Indeed I followed your hint and was able to solve the issue. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Hi Michel, how did you fix this issue?

Comment: As indicated in the comment above. The line of code: "sheet(isPresented: $showingOtherView)" is not what you want to use in this case. As indicated by aheze "sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)" is the kind of code one should use.