# SwiftUI share sheet connection invalidated when creating new view

Tags: swiftui, ios-sharesheet

I have a ShareSheet on my app that works correctly, however when I create a new view I get the error
**UIHostingController which is already presenting and connection invalidated .** My error happens on a List View in my app but I am able to also replicate it using the code below . If I just tap the **Share text** it will work however if I tap the **New View text** and then try to share I will get the **invalidated** error .  I have been looking at other examples to try and fix this but I still get the issue, any suggestions would be great . (I am using SwiftUI 3)

[SwiftUI [Presentation] / Attempt to present View on ... which is already presenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180982/swiftui-presentation-attempt-to-present-view-on-which-is-already-present)

`import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var NewView = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Share")
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture() {
                ShareSheet("http://www.yahoo.com")
            }
        
        Text("New View")
            .onTapGesture() {
                NewView.toggle()
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $NewView, content: {
               ContentView()
            })
    }
}

func ShareSheet(_ url: String) {
    guard let urlShare = URL(string: url) else { return }
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [urlShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.isModalInPresentation = true
    print(UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes)
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    window?.rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true,completion: nil)
    

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}`

</code

Comment: This should be helpful (about integration) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694099/12299030

Comment: perfect thanks a lot that solved the issue